# Fitting composed model to experimental data

Tags: equation-solving, fitting

I have mathematical model based on equation:

$y(x) = 1 - \sum_{b=1}^{\inf} 2c_b \sin(c_b x/L) \exp(ax) $ (1),

where $c_b$ are the positive roots of equation:

$c_b \cot c_b + aL = 0$ (2).

$L$ is a known constant, and $a$ is parameter.
I would like to fit the model to experimental data and obtain value of $a$.

How to implement model based on system of such equations to *Mathematica's* FindFit? In particular, my problem lies in the second equation, which has more than one solution, and every positive one must be accounted in eq.1. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Wait, equation (2) has arbitrarily large roots for $c_b$, so your model contains massively oscillating terms $c_b\sin(c_b x/L)$? That doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 1):

Using only the first `cbMax` amount of $c_b$s, we get:

```
getmodel[a_, cbMax_] := With[{cb = Table[FindRoot[cb Cot[cb] + a L, {cb, Pi (n + 1/2), 
n Pi, (n + 1) Pi}][[1, 2]], {n, 0, cbMax}]},
1 - Sum[2 cb[[i]] Sin[cb[[i]] x/L] E^(a x), {i, cbMax + 1}]]
```

And now notice that for the rest of the $c_b$s, the difference becomes constant (Pi) very fast:

```
ListPlot[Differences[Table[FindRoot[cb Cot[cb] + 1, {cb, Pi (n + 1/2),
n Pi, (n + 1) Pi}][[1, 2]], {n, 0, 100}]]]
```

[image]

Hence a good approximation to account for the rest of the $c_b$s could be

```
FullSimplify[Sum[2 (cb[[-1]] + i Pi) Sin[(cb[[-1]] + i Pi) x/L] E^(a x), {i, \[Infinity]}]]
(*(2 E^((a + (I Pi)/L) x) ((Pi + cb[[-1]]) Sin[(x cb[[-1]])/L] - 
cb[[-1]] Sin[(x (Pi + cb[[-1]]))/L]))/(-1 + E^((I Pi x)/L))^2*)
```

So the final expression for the model function becomes:

```
getmodel[a_, cbMax_] := With[{cb = Table[FindRoot[cb Cot[cb] + a L,
{cb, Pi (n + 1/2), n Pi, (n + 1) Pi}][[1, 2]], {n, 0, cbMax}]},
1 - Sum[2 cb[[i]] Sin[cb[[i]] x/L] E^(a x), {i, cbMax + 1}] -
((2 E^((a + (I Pi)/L) x) ((Pi + cb[[-1]]) Sin[(x cb[[-1]])/L] - 
cb[[-1]] Sin[(x (Pi + cb[[-1]]))/L]))/(-1 + E^((I Pi x)/L))^2)]
```

Depending on the `x`-values of your data, `a` and `L` choose some `cbMax` that is sufficiently high for the model to converge and then do:

```
error[a_?NumericQ] := (
y[x_] = getmodel[a, cbMax]; Total[(dataY - Map[y, dataX])^2])

FindArgMin[error[a], {a, 1, 2}]
```

And there is `a`.